# Store Address Change on PDF Invoice Magento

Tags: magento, pdf, street-address

I must be missing something simple here, but can't figure it out.  I changed the address of my store, however the pdf invoices still have the old address on them.  Where do I need to change this?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see store address on PDF as default Magento functionality. Are you sure this wasn't a custom solution?

Comment: Hi, this is not a custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

For those who need an answer;
Go to

```
System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Invoice and Packing Slip Design
```

and change the address there. Changing here will change the address printed in PDF prints of Order/Invoices